# How do I know whether to use OnComplete or OnSuccess?

Tags: java, firebase

I tried to find an answer online for it, but I couldn't find one which is specific for `Firebase` implementations.

I can choose between `OnCompleteListener` and `OnSuccessListener` for a lot of operations in `Firebase`, and I'd like to know how can I choose between them?.

I have read the documentation for [OnComplete](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/java/reference/com/google/firebase/tasks/OnCompleteListener) and [OnSuccess](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/java/reference/com/google/firebase/tasks/OnSuccessListener), but as I can see from Firebase documentations, [this one](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data) for example, for one specific operation (like `get` operation in the example), they sometimes use `OnSuccessListener` and sometimes they use `OnCompleteListener`.

How can I know which one is better in every situation?
Does it matter? Considering that I'd like to know for every operation if it was succussful or not.

Answer (score 70, accepted):

As the name suggests, `onSuccess()` will fire when a task is completed successfully.

`onComplete()` will fire when the task is completed, even if it failed.

In the method, you can call `Task.isSuccessful()` and `Task.getException()`.

In `onSuccess()` you can be certain that `isSuccessful()` will return true, and `getException()` will return null (so there's not much point calling them).

In `onComplete()` `isSuccessful()` may be `false`, and you have the opportunity to deal with the failure, perhaps using `getException()` to obtain more detail.

If you need to handle failed tasks (and you should!), you have two choices:

1. Use and `OnCompleteListener`, and `if(task.isSuccessful()) { ... } else {...}` -- this puts the success and failure code close together, and may be useful if those routines share state.
2. Use separate `OnSuccessListener` and `OnFailureListener` -- this allows you to write listeners with a bit more cohesion, in that each handler specialises in one thing. Of course, one class may implement both interfaces, giving you another way to have both see the same state.

Comment: That was an excellent explanation on both methods, but didn't really answer why (when) to use one or the either. I guess if you really care about OOP principles you'd choose OnSuccess, to increase cohesion.

Comment: You deserve a medal. That was an awesome explanation.

Answer (score 5):

To add to what [slim](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46649954/7809801) answered above in my use of `Firebase`. 
I find out that this two listeners (`OnCompleteListener` and `OnSuccessListener`)

Have different callback times in writing data to their servers.

**The general rule of thumb**

If you're relying on a systematic(*sequential*) way of writing to the servers in order to 
perform some logic then use `OnCompleteListener`

If you're not dependent on a systematic(*non-sequential i.e async tasks*) way of writing to the servers in order to 
perform some logic then use `OnSuccessListener`

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes you may find that you need to use value of the result say for example getting device token.. only the onSuccess will give InstanceIdResult and not onComplete... so therefore you must use onSuccess...

```
// Get The Device Token And Put It Into Firebase Instance
FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getInstanceId().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<InstanceIdResult>() {
    @Override
    public void onSuccess(InstanceIdResult instanceIdResult) {

        String DeviceToken = instanceIdResult.getToken();

    }
});
```